# Echo dentro de um Array

Tags: php

Estou com a seguinte situação:

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'showposts'=>-1);
    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $count = 0 ;
    if($my_posts) : foreach ($my_posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
     ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pad-b">   
        <!-- modal -->

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(false, array('type'=>'button', 'class'=>'img-responsive', 'data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target'=>'#myModal<?php echo $count; ?>')); ?>

        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal<?php echo $count; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- fim modal -->
    </div>

    <?php
        $count ++ ;
        endforeach;
        endif;
     ?>
```

Eu preciso que o $count seja impresso dentro do array data-target do the_post_thumbnail.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(false, array('type'=>'button', 'class'=>'img-responsive', 'data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target'=>'#myModal<?php echo $count; ?>')); ?>
```

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: `'data-target'=>"#myModal{$count}"` ?

Comment: Obrigado. Eu tinha tenado o ($count), mas não me atentei para a diferença de " " para ' '. Abraços